# C2dm with a webservice to get updates from a xml file

Tags: android, android-c2dm, push-notification

is there a tutorial that shows how to use Android Device to Cloud Messaging Framework c2dm with a web service to get updates in an xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of resources which show how to use C2DM. I'm using them to build a messaging system with REST calls to a WCF service - the code's not that different. [Marakana](http://marakana.com/forums/android/general/272.html) is pretty good as well as [Lars Vogel's Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)